# Why separable closure is normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I feel confused about why the separable closure $K^{\text{sep}}$ of a field $K$ is a Galois extension, i.e. normal. I'm new to Galois theory.

According to the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27316/separable-and-algebraic-closures), it seems we need to "relate the group theory of the absolute Galois group $Gal(K^{\text{sep}}/K)$ with the field theory of Galois extensions of $K$." But I still cannot figure out how to do the relation.

Comment: How do you define the separable closure?

Comment: The set of all elements in the algebraic closure of $K$ that are separable over $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K^{\text{alg}}$ be one algebraic closure of $K$. By your definition, $K^{\text{sep}} = \{x \in K^{\text{alg}} : x \text{ is sepparable over } K\}$.

To prove that $K^{\text{sep}} / K$ is normal, we need to show that its closed under $K$-conjugates.

Let $\theta \in K^{\text{sep}}$ be an arbitrary element, since $\theta$ is sepparable over $K$, its minimal polynomial over $K$, let's say $m(x)$, is sepparable. So all other roots of $m(x)$ (the $K$-conjugates of $\theta$) are also sepparable over $K$ (since they have a sepparable minimal polynomial), therefore they all lie on $K^{\text{sep}}$ too, so its closed under $K$-conjugates.